# Is there a more efficient way to allocate lots of instances of a class in a loop?

Tags: python, performance

I am working on a Python program, and there is an inner loop which is causing performance problems. I ran a profiler on it, and I found that 50% of the time is spent in object allocation. Basically, something like this:

```
result_list = []
for i in range(BIG_NUMBER):
    obj = MyClass()
    # do stuff with obj...
    result_list.append(obj)
```

The line `obj = MyClass()` takes 50% of the time. Is there any way to efficiently allocate lots of these objects in Python? Perhaps some sort of bulk allocation?

Without copy / pasting the entire `MyClass`, it has the following characteristics:

- It is an ORM object, so it basically maps attributes to database values
- It has quite a few property functions, a meta class, etc. so it's a pretty "fat" class

The `# do stuff with obj...` line largely sets the various attributes, usually via `setattr`, but in a few cases via a custom function. So if there are 10 attributes to set, 9 will usually be via `setattr`, and 1 might be via a special function. This part takes ~40% of the time and I'm optimizing it separately.

Comment: can you add `# do stuff with obj...` mean, it's crucial in answering the question.

Comment: Also it depends on MyClass - could it use `__slots__`? Subclass a `namedtuple`?

Comment: This performance overhead is due to the fact that function calls are expensive by nature. `MyClass()` calls the metaclass's `__calll__` method which in return calls the class's `__new__` and `__init__`. Three levels of function calls to create an instance of `MyClass` object, that's why it takes longer time.

Comment: An ORM can do a lot of hidden work. If you don't need validation, for instance, maybe you could try to disable or get around it (write directly in its hidden storage structure).

Comment: Can you do  a 'bulk allocation' first `result_list = [ MyClass() for i in xrange(BIG_NUMBER)]`  and then set all attributes etc in loop? It should speed it up a bit.

Comment: Depending on use you could maybe create own class for `result_list` object so that it recycles already used `MyClass` objects and "does stuff with obj" when it is requested from `result_list`.

Comment: what is `MyClass.__init__`?  If the initialization is taking half the time I'd think the code for the initialization is the most relevant here.

Answer (score -2):

If the object starts w an empty constructor call, could you not pull it out if the loop?  Then **copy.deepcopy** your seed object?